# Make "a" tags, whenever it is clicked, add inner text inside it, but remove when another "a" tag (same class) is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a **Color Change function** for my project. This is my html:

[image: HTML screenshot]

I want to create some tags which have the same class like this: `<a class="dropdown-item" onclick...></a>`

And whenever a user click on 1 of those tags, that tag the user clicked will have an extra text `[current]` like this: `Sky [current]`. But when **another tag** is clicked, the text `[current]` will move to the **new tag (with the same class)** which the user just clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach is to just remove the extra text from every clickable element, then add it to the one that was clicked.

Here's an example.

```js
function addText(event) 
{
  for (anchorTag of document.getElementsByClassName("myButton")){
    anchorTag.innerHTML = anchorTag.innerHTML.replace(" Grape", "");
  }
  event.target.innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML + " Grape";
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="addText(event)">Apple</a>
<br/>
<a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="addText(event)">Orange</a>
```